# CSS Selector for the first drop down on website

Tags: excel, vba, css-selectors

In the HTML page while inspecting a drop-down I press Ctrl + F to find the drop-down css selector and it is like that

```
div .wrapperDropdown
```

But I found two drop-down lists with the same css selector . the first has tab index = 1 and the second has tab index = 2
How to refer to the first one whose tab index = 1

```html
<div class="dropDownDiv">

<div class="wrapper-demo">
<div class="wrapperDropdown icon-downArrow active" tabindex="1">
<span>السعودية</span>
<ul class="dropdown" id="ulCountryList">
<li><a class="Country" countryid="1">مصر</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="13">السعودية</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="14">الإمارات</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="15">المغرب</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="17">تونس</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="18">العراق</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="19">البحرين</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="20">الكويت</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="21">الجزائر</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="23">سلطنةعمان</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="24">قطر</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="27">لبنان</a></li>
<li><a class="Country" countryid="28">الأردن</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper-demo">
<div class="wrapperDropdown icon-downArrow" tabindex="2">
<span>الرياض</span>
 <ul class="dropdown" id="ulCityList">
<li><a class="City" cityid="27">جدة</a></li>
<li><a class="City" cityid="28">الرياض</a></li>
<li><a class="City" cityid="29">مكة</a></li>
<li><a class="City" cityid="85">الجبيل</a></li>
<li><a class="City" cityid="86">الدمام</a></li>
<li><a class="City" cityid="87">الظهران</a></li>
<li><a class="City" cityid="88">الخبر</a></li>
<li><a class="City" cityid="89">المدينه</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I could solve the point of selecting the first drop-down but I can't select an option from it and I got error at the last line

```
Dim ie          As New InternetExplorer
Dim html        As HTMLDocument
Dim drp         As HTMLFormElement
Dim x           As Long
Dim e, r As Long

ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "https://www.masrawy.com/Islameyat/Prayer-Times"
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
Set html = ie.document

Set drp = html.querySelector("div .wrapperDropdown[tabindex='1']")

drp.selectedIndex = 2
```

Comment: I can solve the point of selcting the first drop-down using `div .wrapperDropdown[tabindex="1"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming default is first active then use faster class selector of

```
.wrapperDropdown.active
```

Otherwise, shorten your existing to

```
.wrapperDropdown[tabindex='1']
```

being sure to use single quotes round number or double up on ".

To select an item, as they are anchor tags you need to click and can use nth-of-type to index into li nodes

```
html.querySelector(".wrapperDropdown[tabindex='1'] li:nth-of-type(2) a").Click
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have used `Set drp = html.querySelector(".wrapperDropdown[tabindex='1']") ` but still got an error at this part `drp.selectedIndex = 2`. The problem now is how to select from this drop-down?

Comment: should open a new question. However, looks like anchor tag so try document.querySelector(".wrapperDropdown[tabindex='1'] li:nth-of-type(2) a").click

Comment: Why new question..? The issue is only for selecting the options of that css selector? This is the only problem here my tutor?

Comment: This worked well `html.querySelector(".wrapperDropdown[tabindex='1'] li:nth-of-type(2) a").Click`. Thanks a lot. But the drop-down is still open after selecting. How can I fix that?

Comment: Does it matter that it is still open?

Comment: Yes I need to deal with the second drop-down so I am not sure if it will work if it still open or not?

Comment: Try working with the second and see. .Focus on the second might close the first.

Comment: I have tried the same line again. That's I clicked twice :)